# How to allow Messages notifications to show?

Tags: notifications, google-messages

A couple weeks ago I suddenly stopped getting notifications for the Messages app. I'm still receiving text messages, with no delays.But no notifications are showing up in the top notifications bar. And the phone is not vibrating to indicate that a new message was received. I have a bluetooth connected watch that used to display new messages; that also is not showing alerts for new messages.

I'm pretty sure that the text message app that I'm using is just called "Messages". The icon is a white speech bubble on a blue circle.

I keep missing new texts. The only way to see that there are new unread texts is to manually open the Messages app, and check all the conversations to see if any replies are in *bold* text (indicating that they are unopened).

I have already clicked the three vertical dots "Settings", "Notifications"
The following settings are already on:

- All Message notifications: ON
- Other Notifications: ON
- Data Download Notification Channel: ON
- Allow Notification dot: ON

Android version: 11
Device: Pixel 2
Provider: Verizon

Comment: `Settings > Apps > "The messaging app" > notifications` check if everything is fine here. Or in some devices the path is `Settings > Notifications > "The messaging app" ` . Tell if that works.. i'll explain the reason in the answer

Comment: Also just in case, check if Do Not Disturb is activated or not.

Comment: There is nothing under `Settings` called `Apps`. There is a menu called `Apps and Notifications` there, but there is no "Messages" (or any app names) in that menu.
There is also no `Settings > Notifications`  menu.

Comment: Is there any other setting or action to re-enable notifications? Neither of the settings suggested in the above comment actually exist.